# How much time will take to insert 5,00,000 records in to my SQL server?

Tags: java, database

I have one table. From Java I am trying inserting records to table by batch wise (*batch size: 5000*).
There is no idle time from Java side.

- Can you please let me know how much time it will take for inserting
  5,00,000 records (with indexes).
- How much time it will for inserting 5,00,000 records (with out
  indexes).

Comment: That depends on so many things, such as how many other concurrent connections exist to your MySQL database, how many indices you have setup on the table, etc.  Your question is probably too broad, so you should try to narrow it down.

Comment: Assuming you mean "Lakhs", that's not a unit of measurement everyone knows

Comment: Can i concurrent inserts in to same table?If can you please let me know how to implement in java

Comment: That wouldn't be recommended because you should be performing transactional writes to the database table. But it's possible considering how commonly databases are used by multiple people at once in very large organizations

Comment: You're not likely to get someone to write code for you though before you show your own attempts at the solution

Comment: It really depends on too many things... Any index on the table will add overhead as will any constraint or trigger. And it will give different times if you want one single commit after loading everything (high overhead due to the requirement on rollback segments), one commit per record (high overhead due to the number of commits) or one commit for a *reasonable* number of records. That number also depends on the size of the record and the size of a *page* for the database. Long story made short: you will have to try to get the answer...

Comment: I have 5 lacks records processing from java ..for this started with multiple threads to process these 5 lacks records and added  into array blocking queue from queue executing  batch runner  (batch size is 5000) .In table i have 2 indexs and there is blob data and i have 15 colums. For this design it tooks around 4 to 5 mins complete 5 lacks records.As per my analysis there is no ideal time from java side.But it's taking time from data base(mySQL).Is there any better approch or arch to reduce time. help me on this.Thanks Advance

Answer (score -2):

Depends on your Hardware and your tables. A single table with 20 column without `blob` datatype. It should take around ~3-4min.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you provide more details about how you did this benchmarking?

Comment: BLOB, you mean?

Comment: I have 5 lacks records processing from java ..for this started with multiple threads to process these 5 lacks records and added into array blocking queue from queue executing batch runner (batch size is 5000) .In table i have 2 indexs and there is blob data and i have 15 colums. For this design it tooks around 4 to 5 mins complete 5 lacks records.As per my analysis there is no ideal time from java side.But it's taking time from data base(mySQL).Is there any better approch or arch to reduce time. help me on this.Thanks Advance